# Block Connections From Particular Country On AWS EC2

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am having a server on AWS. It currently serves the application for USA and India. But I see that hackers are trying to access it from China, Russia, ... other countries.

Is there any option in AWS security groups or somewhere to block request apart from USA and India.

[image: Google Analytics Data Showing Sessions From Other Countries]

Comment: Before you try to solve this problem, you need to verify whether it's actually a problem.  Geocoding of IP space a is an art, not a science, as evidenced by the fact that 8.5%(!) of your traffic isn't even identified as any country.  A secure application should not need to blacklist source traffic from unexpected places, and some of this traffic could be legitimate.

Answer (score 1):

No unfortunately there isn't, however you can still use something like [freegeoip.net](http://freegeoip.net) or [pam_geoip](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pam_geoip.8.html) to filter access to your application.